# Trying to make comments editable in django

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app and the comments can be added on the detail page of the blog, im having trouble implementing a way for users to edit comments they have already made. I have it so a url shows up on comments where only the person signed in can click the link to edit their comments on the post however im getting this error when I try to load the detail page now. Any help would be appreciated thank you

Reverse for 'update_comment' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/update$']

edit:
I corrected my detail.html file and now im getting this error:
update_comment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from Date.utils import unique_slug_generator
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                    self).get_queryset()\
                         .filter(status='cleared')
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('cleared','Cleared'),('UnderReview','Being Reviewed'),('banned','Banned'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 300, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='forum_posts',null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='cleared')
    objects = models.Manager()
    cleared = PublishedManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering =('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])

def slug_generator(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(slug_generator, sender=Post)
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='comments',null=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.name} on {self.post}'
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .views import PostListView, PostCreateView,PostUpdateView
app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    #path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/update/',PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/<int:comment_id>/update',views.update_comment, name='update_comment'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, Comment
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from .forms import CommentForm, PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse



class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.cleared.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'posts/post/list.html'



"""class PostDetailView(DetailView, Post):
    queryset = Post.cleared.all()
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body']
    template_name = 'posts/post/detail.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Post,
            publish__year=self.kwargs['year'],
            publish__month=self.kwargs['month'],
            publish__day=self.kwargs['day'],
            slug=self.kwargs['post'],
        )
        return post
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['comment'] = Comment.objects.all()
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
        comment_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'comment_form': comment_form})"""
           
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body']
    template_name = 'posts/post-update.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Post,
            publish__year=self.kwargs['year'],
            publish__month=self.kwargs['month'],
            publish__day=self.kwargs['day'],
            slug=self.kwargs['post'],
            author=self.request.user
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail',
            args=[
                self.object.publish.year,
                self.object.publish.month,
                self.object.publish.day,
                self.object.slug
            ]
        )
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post, comment_id = None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post = post
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user
            comment_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'posts/post/detail.html', {'post':post , 'comments': comments,'comment_form': comment_form, 'comment_id':comment_id })

def update_comment(request, year, month, day, post,id, comment_id = None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post , slug=post, status='cleared',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day, id=id)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    comment_form = CommentForm
    if comment_id:
        comment_form = CommentForm(instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id), data=request.POST)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment_form.instance.post = post
                comment_form.instance.name = request.user
                comment_form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'posts/update_comment.html', {'post':post , 'comments': comments,'comment_form': comment_form, 'comment_id':comment_id })
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment,Post

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields =('title','body',)
```

detail.html

```
 {% extends "Main/Base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}<h1>
    <p class="date">
        Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
        {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
            <h3><a href="{% url 'posts:post-update' post.publish.year post.publish.month post.publish.day post.slug %}">Update your post</a></h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
        <h2>
            {{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}
        </h2>
    {% endwith %}
        {% for comment in comments %}
            <div class="comment">
                <p class="info">
                    Comment by {{comment.name }}
                    {{ comment.created }}
                </p>
                {{ comment.body|linebreaks}}
                {% if user.is_authenticated and user == comment.name %}
                    <p><a href="{% url 'posts:update_comment' post.publish.year post.publish.month post.publish.day post.slug comment.id %}">edit</a></p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <p>There are no comments yet.</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% if new_comment %}
        <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
    {% else %}
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
            <form method="post">
                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
            </form>
        {% else %}
        <h3>You need to be logged in to make a comment please <a href="{% url 'login' %}">log-in</a> if you dont have an account register <a href="{% url 'register' %}">here now</a></h3>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}   
{% endblock %}
```

update_comment.html

```
{% extends "Main/Base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'posts:update_comment' post.publish.year post.publish.month post.publish.day post.slug comment.id %}">
                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
            </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Ive been trying a bunch of this to try and make it work so my code is a bit of a mess, there aren't many tutorials on making editable comments with django.

Comment: `{% url 'posts:update_comment' comment_id %}` does not make much sense, since it expects a year, month, day, slug and comment id.

Comment: yeah good point I have been struggling on this for a while I missed that